# Wix : will adding same feature group Id under different features with different conditions removes the already added features?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Consider the following .wxs

```
<Feature Id="Prod.Full" Level="1" Title="!(loc.FeatureAllFiles)">
  <Condition Level="0"><![CDATA[NOT((MYPRODINSTALLATIONTYPE ~= "FULL") OR (MYPRODINSTALLATIONTYPE ~=""))]]></Condition>
  <FeatureGroupRef Id="FeatureGroup.FullA"/>
  <FeatureGroupRef Id="FeatureGroup.FullB"/>
  <FeatureGroupRef Id="FeatureGroup.FullC"/>
</Feature>

<Feature Id="Prod.AddCompFree" Level="1" Title="!(loc.FeatureAdditionalFiles)">
  <Condition Level="0"><![CDATA[NOT((MYPRODINSTALLATIONTYPE ~= "FREE") OR (MYPRODINSTALLATIONTYPE ~=""))]]></Condition>
  <FeatureGroupRef Id="FeatureGroup.FullB"/>
</Feature>
```

Imagine i am running the msi with MYPRODINSTALLATIONTYPE =FULL

Will the installtion  have all the three feature groups (FeatureGroup.FullA,"FeatureGroup.FullB,"FeatureGroup.FullC)

or

will FeatureGroup.FullB will be removed in the installation ?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: FeatureGroup.FullB will be removed in the installation

Long Answer: When the CostInitialize/CostFinalize actions are run the Condition table is processed in order: top -> bottom.

This row is processed first, and the condition is FALSE (no features set to InstallLevel=0)

```
<Feature Id="Prod.Full" Level="1" Title="!(loc.FeatureAllFiles)">
  <Condition Level="0"><![CDATA[NOT((MYPRODINSTALLATIONTYPE ~= "FULL") OR (MYPRODINSTALLATIONTYPE ~=""))]]></Condition>
  <FeatureGroupRef Id="FeatureGroup.FullA"/>
  <FeatureGroupRef Id="FeatureGroup.FullB"/>
  <FeatureGroupRef Id="FeatureGroup.FullC"/>
</Feature>
```

This row is processed second, and the condition is TRUE (FeatureGroup.FullB has InstallLevel=0)

```
<Feature Id="Prod.AddCompFree" Level="1" Title="!(loc.FeatureAdditionalFiles)">
  <Condition Level="0"><![CDATA[NOT MYPRODINSTALLATIONTYPE ~= "FREE"]]></Condition>
  <FeatureGroupRef Id="FeatureGroup.FullB"/>
</Feature>
```